# Wpf Resolution Indepence and Native Resolution

Tags: wpf

WPF documentation and tutorials state that WPF is resolution independent which I understood shows a window in the same size in different resolutions (1600x1200 -> native and 1024x768) and/or DPI settings. However, when I tried a sample app. with different resolutions the sizes are different. On the net I found http://www.wpflearningexperience.com/?p=41, which use "native resolution" in order to see the same window size on different computers, however I could not understand the underlying concept.

Why native resolution for LCD is vital and resolution indepence is a term instead of DPI independence? Probably, I do not know/use terminology well, but I need a clarification in order to understand this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to answer my own questions, but I think I got the point. Sorry for this premature question, but after a while I noticed the problem.

As far as I understand WPF uses System DPI (which you set by changing through Windows Desktop Settings) as a scale factor. For example in the tutorial above one of the computers have a native resolution of 1600x1200 and 96 DPI (94 actually as stated in the tutorial). Everything is fine because System DPI (96) is quite close to the real DPI (94) and WPF can use this information to scale your window.

As you know a Device Independent Unit is 1/96 inch and with the numbers above real pixel size (physical pixel on your screen) is multiplied with ( (1/96) * 96 ) which is equal to 1. So if you have a window with 300 DIU, then you will see ( 300/96 ) inch on your screen.

However, when you change your resolution without changing System DPI, here comes the problem which confused my mind. Say, you set the screen resolution to 1024x768 without changing the System DPI (still it is 96) and run the application again and you see a bigger window. This is the reqult of wrong System DPI and naturally wrong scale factor for WPF. WPF does not know much about your real DPI, it only uses the information you give to it which is System DPI. Let's recalculate our window size with this new settings. First we need scale factor which is ( (1/96) * 96 ) equal to 1. We can say that 1 logical pixel is also 1 physical pixel on screen. However, we changed the resolution and 300 pixel is not the same with the previous resolution. Previously we have 1600 pixel on the diagonal which is also 17 inch in length. However, we have 1024 pixel for 17 inch now. 300 pixel is almost 5 inch on our new resolution (1024x768), but only 3.18 inch in the previous resolution (1600x1200). Therefore, WPF cannot be resolution independent due to the wrong DPI value and draws a larger window with the new resolution.

So, how I fix the problem (in my words, I do not claim that this is an absolute solution)! When I change the resolution, I also changed the DPI value which is true for this new resolution. For example, for my own monitor the diagonal size is 17 inch with a resolution of 1024x768, I use the formula (1024 pixel / 17 inch) and find that my new true DPI is almost 60 DPI. I set the System DPI to 60 (through the Desktop Settings of course) and it works. Not perfectly, due to the rounding errors during the calculations, but in practice values can be considered equal.

WPF uses System DPI in order to be resolution independent and you need to set actual DPI (real DPI value for current resolution). You need to set DPI in order to help WPF to be resolution free. Finally (and I think very crucially) you have do one more thing, at least on Windows XP, you need a restart in order to enable your DPI settings with the new value. If you do not (as I did), WPF still make the calculations wrong and draw in different size.

These are my understanding and results from the tests I did, but I cannot claim they are absolute. I just want to share it with the people who may find this information useful. Please comment/edit my post if you find any error or think that needs improvement.